com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:23.3.0 is not compatible with targetSdkVersion 34
I want to upgrade my project to targetSdkVersion 34. As you know when upgrading to targetSdkVersion 34, every single foreground service must specify its type. I have google admob dependency (latest version) in my project:
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:23.3.0'

But apparently this dependency has a foreground service that does not specify its type:
   <service
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        tools:ignore="MissingClass" />

I can't remove this dependency because I've used it many times in my project and I really need it.

I have a question. You mentioned implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:23.3.0' in your post. Do you have to update it every time Mobile Ads SDK releases a new version? Because I see the version 23.2.0 was released in June, 2024 while version 23.3.0 in August, 2024. I'm looking to get Google Analytics statistics by including the suggested code.

@rusty No, we decided to upgrade all our application's dependencies after almost 3 years.
